# setTimeout in Vue method not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, settimeout

In my small Vue application, I'm trying to call the same method (emptyDivision) with different parameters from within another method (buttonClick). I set a 5-second timeout for the first invocation of that method, but this delay is not being recognized when I trigger these two functions by executing buttonClick.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="app">
           <button v-on:click="buttonClick">Simulate Placement</button>
           <h1>Random Division 1</h1>
           <p>{{A.One}}</p>
           <p>{{A.Two}}</p>
           <h1>Random Division 2</h1>
           <p>{{B.One}}</P>
           <p>{{B.Two}}</p>
       </div> 
       <script type="text/javascript">
          new Vue({
              'el': '#app',
              'data': {
                  'A': {'One': "", 'Two': "" },
                  'B': {'One': "", 'Two': "" },
                  'Division1': ["Steelers", "Ravens"],
                  'Division2': ["Broncos", "Raiders"],
              }, 
              'methods': {
                'emptyDivision': function(division){
                   this.A[division] = this.popTeam(division)[0];
                   this.B[division] = this.popTeam(division)[0];
                },
                'popTeam': function(division) {
                   if (division === "One"){
                     return this.Division1.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.Division1.length), 1);
                   }
                   return this.Division2.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.Division2.length), 1);
                },
                'buttonClick': function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {console.log("This appears after 3 seconds")}, 3000);
                    setTimeout(this.emptyDivision("One"), 5000); /*Teams in division one
            ("Steelers" and "Ravens") should be propagated to the DOM after 5 seconds, but it's being
            evaluated at the same time as the invocation to this.emptyDivision("Two") */

                   this.emptyDivision("Two"); /* I expect ("Broncos" and "Raiders" to be rendered to the DOM
            first due to the timeout, but this is not happening*/
        }
      }
    })
  </script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

After inspecting the console, the three-second timeout log statement is evaluated and produces the expected behavior, but the five-second timeout to emptyDivision("one") does not appear to be working, as detailed by the comments I left in the above code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case you are passing a function definition to setTimeout which will be executed once it is resolved.

In the second case you are directly executing the function, so you need to wrap the statement into a function:

```
setTimeout( () => this.emptyDivision('one'), 5000)
```

If emptyDivision returned a function then that function would be executed after the timeout and you wouldn't need to wrap it.